# How do i remove string form a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

Here is my column :

```
column
abc1234
abc5678
abc4567
```

Now I need to remove the `abc` only from the column.  Please help me write a query.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^abc', '')
WHERE col LIKE 'abc%';
```

If you don't care about the particular position of `abc`, and accept removing all occurrences of it anywhere, then we can do without regex:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = OREPLACE(col, 'abc', '')
WHERE col LIKE 'abc%';
```

Comment: In Teradata, the name of the function in the second example would be OREPLACE